# Hello-jni sample doesn't work in Android Studio 2.0 Preview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm trying to implement [`hello-jni` sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-jni)
into my project. I have `Gradle` 2.8 and `'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.4.0'` and using `Android Studio 2.0 Preview 3b`.

This is my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"
        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "lala.lala"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 16
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"
        }
    }
    /*
    * native build settings
    */
    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "hello-jni"


        //  cppFlags.add("-fno-rtti")
     //    cppFlags.add("-fno-exceptions")
     //   ldLibs.addAll(["android", "log"])
      //  stl       = "system"

    }

    android.productFlavors {
        // for detailed abiFilter descriptions, refer to "Supported ABIs" @
        // https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa
        create("arm") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi")
        }
        create("arm7") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
        }
        create("arm8") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("arm64-v8a")
        }
        create("x86") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("x86")
        }
        create("x86-64") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("x86_64")
        }
        create("mips") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("mips")
        }
        create("mips-64") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("mips64")
        }
        // To include all cpu architectures, leaves abiFilters empty
        create("all")
    }
    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            //proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.txt'))
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.3.0'
}
```

I have created in `JNI` folder `hello-jni.h`:

[image]

In some part of my code I import this:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("hello-jni");
}
public static native int testMethod();
```

And by auto completion created `hello-jni.c`:

```
#include "hello-jni.h"

JNIEXPORT jintJNICALL
Java_lala_lala_HomeScreen_testMethod(JNIEnv
*env,
jclass type
)
{
// TODO
}
```

Header file `hello-jni.h`:

```
//
// Created by Filip on 15.12.2015..
//

#ifndef PHOTO_HELLO_JNI_H
#define PHOTO_HELLO_JNI_H

#endif //PHOTO_HELLO_JNI_H
```

But it doesn't work. It is full red:

[image]

What is problem? How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's problem in Android studio, but just on Windows: [Issue 195483](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=195483&q=label%3AReportedBy-Developer&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)
You can downgrade to Android studio 1.5.1, gradle 2.8,  [experimental wrapper 0.4.0](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental/0-4-0).
I tried Android Studio 2.0 beta 6, with wrapper [0.6.0-beta5](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental) and 0.6.0-beta6, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

To make the sample work you may try the following steps:

1. The signature of the `jni` method `Java_filsoft_photo_HomeScreen_testMethod(...)` does not match to your package name which is `lala.lala`. For the method to be called make its signature consistent with package name.
2. Try editing `hello-jni.c` as follows:

   ```
   #include <jni.h>
   #include "hello-jni.h"

   jint Java_lala_lala_HomeScreen_testMethod( JNIEnv* env, jclass type )
   {
   }
   ```
3. Regarding the red highlightings, as of `Android Studio 2.0 Preview 3b` the `NDK` feature is not yet officially supported and, to my best guess, this is the reason for it. Disable `Android NDK support` plugin (if installed)

   `Settings` > `Plugins` > uncheck `Android NDK support` > restart `Android Studio`

Comment: Oh that is not problem, i'm put placeholder on one place and forget to put it on another.. It is consistent, I have problem with `#include <jni.h>`

Comment: It cannot find this library

Comment: ndk.dir=C\:\\Users\\Filip\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk\\ndk-bundle
Yes

Comment: I think yes, i dont change anything in this file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98026/discussion-between-filip-v-and-onik).

Comment: it works now but Sintax checker highlight red all code

Comment: Well it works good, editor shows a lot of red lines(imports etc...), but it compiles and works, do you know how to resolve this editor problem?

Comment: I'm not at home right now, code compiles perfectly but editor shows error with includes and everything which use some method from libraries. But it works.

Comment: Yes ok,  I will accept it, but can you help me with this false editor errors? It it irritating.