# Android Studio 2.0's inline compiler does no longer recognize native code

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I am currently working on a library that contains Java and native code.

The build works well, and so does the execution of the code when this lib is used by a client application. But the inline compiler of Android Studio 2.0 beta 2 does no longer recognize my NDK code properly (while this was OK with Studio 1.5):

- All natives appear red in the Java code while they are properly mapped through `JNI_OnLoad()`:

[image: native looks broken]

- The whole C code is highlighted in red as Studio cannot find the includes and symbols:

[image: red C includes]

...
[image: red C code]

I didn't have this problem before switching from Android Studio 1.5 to Studio 2.0 beta 2. Studio was able to reverse engineer the code in a way the `JNI_OnLoad()` mapping between the Java native methods and native C code was detected. `#include<>` directives and so on were OK too.

I don't know how to restore this behaviour: I investigated in [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com) and here in SO but I found nothing about that. I also digged into the Studio Settings with no success. I'm still investigating though.

My Gradle settings follow:

- **Gradle version: 2.10**
- **gradle.properties:**

  ```
  android.useDeprecatedNdk = true
  ```
- **Project's build.gradle:**

  ```
  buildscript {
      repositories {
          jcenter()
      }
      dependencies {
          classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta2'
      }
  }

  allprojects {
      repositories {
          jcenter()
      }
  }

  task clean(type: Delete) {
      delete rootProject.buildDir
  }
  ```
- **Module's build.gradle:**

  ```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

  android {
      compileSdkVersion 23
      buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

      defaultPublishConfig 'release'
      publishNonDefault true

      defaultConfig {
          minSdkVersion 16
          targetSdkVersion 21
      }

      compileOptions {
          sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
          targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
      }

      buildTypes {
          release {
              ndk {
                  moduleName "mylib"
                  ldLibs "log"
              }

              debuggable false
              jniDebuggable false
              minifyEnabled false
          }

          debug {
               ndk {
                   moduleName "mylib"
                   ldLibs "log"
                   cFlags "-g"
               }

               debuggable true
               jniDebuggable true
               minifyEnabled false
          }
      }

      productFlavors {
          library {
          }
      }
  }

  dependencies {
      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  }
  ```

As I suspected the debug info to be missing for the IDE to do the reverse engineering properly, I also tried using exactly the same config for `debug` and `release` (with the `-g` flag on, `debuggable true`, and `jniDebuggable true`), but this doesn't change anything.

**EDIT, 20160212:** researches led me to think this is a bug in the NDK integration of Studio 2.0, so I opened [a Google Code ticket](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=200800).

Comment: Would [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34298780/hello-jni-sample-doesnt-work-in-android-studio-2-0-preview) help?

Comment: @Onik Hi, and thanks a lot for this. It doesn't help though as this link shows how to make the C code signature to comply to the default JNI mapping (which basically consists in naming the C code function in a way it matches the Java classe's fully qualified name  + the native function method). What I'm doing here is different: I'm using an explicit matching declared in the `JNI_Onload() ` C function that is called at JNI startup time. The strange thing is that is used to work with Studio 1.5 (I didn't change a single line of my C code, neither I did change any line of my Java code).

Comment: I actually meant the item #3 of the answer on the link regarding disabling `NDK` plugin in attempt to get rid of the code being highlighted.

Comment: @Onik Oh, sorry! Yes, this is what I did in the meantime to prevent my screen from being all red... while awaiting for a fix :) Thanks again!

Comment: I'm in exactly this boat. After hours of trial and error getting an acceptable C++ experience in 1.5.1 and upgrading to 2 then 2.1 I can't even get code formatting to work in native. Lucky I got most of my javah signatures before the move. 1.5.1 was so cool in even wrapping array access for you. 2.x makes a pigs ear of formatting. The long proferred native support should be here next update. Right.

Comment: apply plugin: 'cpp'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in Android Studio 2.2, but [only for 64 bits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37754201/840960). The deprecated NDK toolchain must be replaced by [CMake](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html) in the project configuration.

Comment: I am running AS 3.1.4 and it is still the case, complaints about JNIEXPORT and JNICALL and about everything in the ANSI standard include files (with Cmake), red underline. Compiling works no problem, but the editor alert is good, but no unusable because it warns for everything (claiming JNIEXPORT and JNICALL  is Microsoft stuff).

Comment: And is your NDK bundle up-to-date too? It could be the reason.

Comment: Could be that the configuration comes from AS hello jni from the time of AS2?

Comment: @JanBergström Hard to say actually, that's strange. And do you also experience issue when setting breakpoints in native code? I remember I had the two issues, both solved at the same time if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Breakpoints works, debugging (all data is OK displayed) works, compiling works but the editor red-mark about all standard functions from the ANSI libraries and the jni.h. Also saying that locally defined things like BITMASK (define _int64) is MS stuff not supported etc. Locally defined NULL is not red underscore but red text. Right side of the editor is like a red line. (It is like the AS 3.1.4 (and many versions earlier) editor don't find the include files but the compiler do.

Comment: The editor sometimes add a top hierarchy include statement  (most likely of the same reason) and of course the compiler makes error stop. This is another topic of the Stackoverflow, and it might be the same issue?

Comment: Add include statements on low level in the C/Java interface JNI-c-file but not in the regular C-files (that are the same as in my common OS code (as also used in the Win32 version etc).

Comment: @JanBergström And you are not using `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true` in your `gradle.properties`, are you?

Comment: Using android.useDeprecatedNdk=true the red alerts disappear and if I misspell something it is red alereted OK.

Comment: But, I havent selected using a Deprecated Ndk, and have no reasons for it.

Comment: I started when AS was pretty new (never used Eclipse) and at one time (I think by the intro of AS2 I had to recreate my entire project again). I both initially created it and later recreated it from the hello-jni sample (to use the project settings from it (that obviously worked). 

I am asking myself, should I or shouldn't I use a a Deprecated Ndk? What are the alternatives? Perhaps should I recreate my project again from the latest hello-jni? My entire NDK-code is pure ANSI C (not C++).  Can you advise me?

Comment: One last comment (advice) is good for me, think it is essential for this thread to be finished. .

Comment: @JanBergström Well, if it was me, I would reconstruct the project, ensuring I am using latest versions of Gradle and NDK (which seems to be what you do). I would also check whether my gradle build file uses `externalNativeBuild { cmake { /* flags: mine are cFlags "-g" in Debug mode, and are cFlags "-fvisibility=hidden -g0 -O3" in release Mode */ }  }`. But I don't see what to do more at that time. Mayfe these flags help, especially those of the Debug mode, as the inline compiler needs a symbol table to recognize the symbols of your code.

Comment: Good to know. Right now it works, but I do commercial SW and it should be right. I check your comment and I will also check the latest hello-jni and try to learn the parameters themselves carefully. If I then still feel there is an issue "Should I use a Deprecated Ndk?" I put it up as a new subject in SO. When new in AS and Android java the parameter issue is overwhelming and copy the hello-jni-setup is a smooth way of getting started. Now is time to understand it.

Comment: After the upgrade AS 3.2 I had to delete the android.useDeprecatedNdk=true in my gradle.properties, and it works fine!

Comment: @JanBergström Good news! Thanks for letting us know. Maybe you could write an answer wto this question with this. I think it's going to be useful to a lot of people.

Comment: Well, it looks like I have to push the Gradle resync button in AS 3.2 every time I start the AS and want the red alerts on standard library functions in NDK to disappear? Need not to do anything else (and useDeprecatedNdk=true removed from gradle.properties), just do Gradle resync. Then all works fine. Odd?

Comment: You know  when I (on suggestion) put useDeprecatedNdk=true in gradle.properties, I had to make a Grade resync (the AS told me to do). So I can't tell if the insert in editing gradle.properties or the Gradle sync action made the difference in AS 3.1?