# android studio editor error jni

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am working on a project using Android and native code through JNI.

Android Studio editor keeps telling me that it cannot resolve the native method yet it compiles an executes my program fine.

```java
// In the Java file
private native void startROSNode();
```

```cpp
// In the C++ file
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_laas_lumusapp_ROSThread_startROSNode(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)
```

Is there something I am missing ? (even if it is not project critical it bugs me to see that red line in my editor :))

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be several reasons, most likely this is due to the ndk 'experimental plugin' (Assuming you have not migrated to CMake). Take a look here, perhaps this will help you: [Android Studio 2.0's inline compiler does no longer recognize native code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35343684/android-studio-2-0s-inline-compiler-does-no-longer-recognize-native-code)